# PDFJs Viewer.html into a div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, pdf.js

Does anyone know if viewer.html from pdf.js (http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) can be placed inside a `<div>`?.

Or better yet, converted to an AngularJs directive (I know there are a couple of pdfjs directives for Angular, but none of them has the quality of viewer.html).

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/legalthings/angular-pdfjs-viewer) is integrating the pdfjs viewer into an angular directive (but rather poorly, imho). Did you happen to find any alternatives meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

Put your src of pdf file in iframe like this :

```
<div><iframe src="/pdfjs/viewer.html/{src of PDF file}" style="position: relative;   top: 0;  bottom: 0; left: 0;   width: 100%;   height: 700px;  border: 0"></iframe></div>
```

it may help you

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely place viewer.html in a `<div>`.

Start with [the source](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) and wrap `<div id="outerContainer">`

in your own `<div>`, which you can then style to your liking:

```
<div id="myContainer">
    <div id="outerContainer">

      <div id="sidebarContainer"> 
      </div>  <!-- sidebarContainer -->

      <div id="mainContainer">
      </div> <!-- mainContainer -->

      <div id="overlayContainer" class="hidden">
      </div>  <!-- overlayContainer -->

    </div> <!-- outerContainer -->
</div>
```

Note that making the width smaller than about 800px squishes the toolbar items.

Comment: in your answer the link to the source returns 404

Answer (score 0):

The following example **loads pdf into a div** using javascript api provided by pdf.js. You can also see [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/vnL47xyd/).

```js
// If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
// header on that server.
var url = '//cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/helloworld.pdf';

// Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

// Asynchronous download of PDF
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
  console.log('PDF loaded');
  
  // Fetch the first page
  var pageNumber = 1;
  pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
    console.log('Page loaded');
    
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
    renderTask.then(function () {
      console.log('Page rendered');
    });
  });
}, function (reason) {
  // PDF loading error
  console.error(reason);
});
```

```css
#the-canvas {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>

<h1>PDF.js 'Hello, world!' example</h1>
<div>
<canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Made something similar starting in Node.js where I am including PDF file to viewer's webpack & start browser. Also added reorder and traverse client logic there https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/compare/gh-pages...eltomjan:gh-pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use `viewer.html` inside an iframe.

1. download the latest library from https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/releases
2. Unzip it. Move the whole `pdfjs` directory inside the `public` directory of your project.
3. Use this code:

```html
    <iframe
      src="/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=/path-to-the-file.pdf"
      :width="500px"
      :height="500px"
      frameborder="0"
    ></iframe>
```